# Bold font when writing to file using fs

Tags: node.js, file, fonts, fs

I have a string that i am writing to a file using fs, is there a way to change the font weight or the color of the font while writing it to the file?

Answer (score 1):

A file generally speaking is a sequence of lines ending with a newline character.

Different file **formats** however may specify other features. Files in those formats will be interpreted by a program that then renders the contents.

For example, [Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) file format allows you to make the text bold with by placing `**` before and after the text you want to make bold.

On it's own, the `fs` module is agnostic of such formats. Thus it may make sense to either abandon the idea or incorporate a Markdown (or any other format) rendering library ([example](https://github.com/chjj/marked)).